# How to best capture and log scp output?

Tags: logging, shell, scp

I am trying to capture output from an install script (that uses scp) and log it.  However, I am not getting everything that scp is printing out, namely, the progress bar.

screen output:

> Copying
>   /user2/cdb/builds/tmp/uat/myfiles/* to
>   server /users/myfiles as cdb
>
> cdb@server's password: 
>   myfile     100% |*****************************|  2503       00:00

log output:

> Copying
>   /user2/cdb/builds/tmp/uat/myfiles/* to
>   server /users/myfiles as cdb

I'd really like to know that my file got there.  Here's what I am trying now to no avail:

> myscript.sh 2>&1 | tee mylogfile.log

Does anyone have a good way to capture scp output and log it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like your just missing whether the scp was succesful or not from the log.

I'm guessing the scroll bar doesn't print to stdout and uses ncurses or some other kind of TUI?

You could just look at the return value of scp to see whether it was successful. Like

```
scp myfile user@host.com:. && echo success!
```

`man scp` says

```
scp exits with 0 on success or >0 if an error occurred.
```

Answer (score 37):

scp prints its progress bar to the terminal using control codes. It will detect if you redirect output and thus omit the progress bar.

You can get around that by tricking scp into thinking it runs in a terminal using the "script" command which is installed on most distros by default:

```
script -q -c "scp server:/file /tmp/" > /tmp/test.txt
```

The content of test.txt will be:

```
file    0%    0     0.0KB/s   --:-- ETA
file   18%   11MB  11.2MB/s   00:04 ETA
file   36%   22MB  11.2MB/s   00:03 ETA
file   54%   34MB  11.2MB/s   00:02 ETA
file   73%   45MB  11.2MB/s   00:01 ETA
file   91%   56MB  11.2MB/s   00:00 ETA
file  100%   61MB  10.2MB/s   00:06
```

...which is probably what you want.

I stumbled over this problem while redirecting the output of an interactive script into a log file. Not having the results in the log wasn't a problem as you can always evaluate exit codes. But I really wanted the interactive user to see the progress bar. This answer solves both problems.

Comment: Beware: you may want to use the `--return` (`-r`) option for `script`, if it is available, so the return code of the child process will be preserved. Otherwise, even if the command fails, your `script` command will happily return a success code.

Comment: The single character for `--return` is actually `-e`.

Answer (score 3):

None of the answers here worked for me, I needed to recursively copy large directory with lot of files over long geo distance, so I wanted to log the **progress** (`&& echo success!` was by far not enough).

What I finally engineered and somehow worked was:

```
scp -vrC root@host:/path/to/directory . 2> copy.log &
```

With `-v` doing the trick of verbose logging (`-C` allows compression and `-r` recursion).

Grepping the logfile

```
grep file copy.log | wc -l
```

allowed me to see the number of files copied so far.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use '[script](http://ayaz.wordpress.com/2006/11/19/script1-logging-terminal-sessions-to-files/)' to log the terminal session.

Answer (score 1):

```
scp myfile user@host.com:. && echo success!
```

is very helpful but to write the message to a log file I changed it like this

```
scp myfile user@host.com:. && echo myfile successfully copied! >> logfile 2>&1
```

and this will write "myfile successfully copied!" message to the log file.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment yet :( so I'll add an update here...

@Martin had the best solution for me although if your scp command is midway through your script then it's output *may* appear after commands that actually ran afterwards.

I think that is because script must run the command in a subshell but I am yet to test.

EDIT: it does indeed spawn a shell so if you need things to run (and indeed fail) in a sequential manner (like in a build script) then you would have to add some logic around the use of the script command.

i.e.

script -q -c "your command" && sleep 1

or something similar so that your parent shell waits for the child shell to finish before moving on.

Comment: script -qc 'sleep 10' blocks execution on my system whereas echo | script -qc 'sleep 10' does not. Workaround: echo | script -qc 'sleep 10' | cat. I think the shell blocks as long as stdin/err/out are still open.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
scp server:/file /tmp/ > /dev/tty
```

Comment: Adding an explanation of this answer would be a good idea. (It also strikes me as unlikely to get the output to his log file.)

Comment: Why did someone downvoted? This is the CORRECT answer. By default scp will omit output when no tty is available, so you can force with >/dev/tty.

Comment: If this is correct, where is the log file?

Answer (score 0):

SCP on my server did not have `-c` option (well `-c` was to specify a cihper) - I needed the rate, so I used below:

```
$ scp -q -v nb3510@servername:sftp.dummy . 2>&1 | grep 'Bytes per second'
Bytes per second: sent 52945.7, received 188047087.0
```

`-v` is for verbose on my server.

Comment: -C (capital C) is for compression

Answer (score -1):

```
$ grep -r "Error" xyz.out > abc.txt
```

Here in the above command I am storing output into file abc.txt.

This `grep` command is for searching text containg *Error* in file *xyz.out* and storing the output in *abc.txt* without displaying on console.

Comment: This is literally not related at all to scp.

Answer (score -2):

yes i recently was trying to get output within a php script from proc_open()
i lost a quiet a time trying to get output :-)
but its a bit late here and i then reading this post here made me realize that i dont really need this junky output to my script

just the exit code will do the job :-)

$exit_code = proc_close($process);

Comment: Although the exit code is available, this is not what that author is asking.